# Android: Adding text to a textview in different xml layout by clicking button

Tags: android, xml, class, button, textview

I just need a little help with the android program that I am making. Basically, I have a button in one of my XML layouts, and when that button is pressed, it should add the name of that activity into a TextView which is located in another XML layout.

So this is the button that needs pressing.

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/add_to_schedule"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/widget44"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/add_to_schedule"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:typeface="serif" />
```

And this is the TextView which is in a different XML Layout that I want it to display the information to.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtview"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="76dp"
        android:text="@string/textview" />
```

This is the class where the Button will be pressed from.

```
public class Aerobic_Steps extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.aerobic_steps);

    }
}
```

And this is the Class which the TextView will belong to.

```
public class Training_Schedule extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.training_schedule);
    }
}
```

Comment: use bundle to pass value to another activity

Comment: when do you want to show the text to other layout? after clicking do you want to start the activity and show the text ? or do you want to show the text on a already active activity

Comment: It should add the text immediately and stay there.

Comment: So yeah after clicking it should start the activity and show the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In class `Aerobic_Steps`, call Training_Schedule activity in `OnClick` of Button

```
public class Aerobic_Steps extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.aerobic_steps);
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById (R.id.buttonName);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);

}
}


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String className = Aerobic_Steps.this.getClass().getSimpleName();
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Training_Schedule.class); 
           i.putExtras("name",className);
            startActivity(i);

}
```

Now in `Training_Schedule` Activity, use below code in `OnCreate()`

```
   //Get the bundle
  Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

  //Extract the data…
  String name = bundle.getString(“name”); 
  TextView tv = (TextView) findViewByID(R.id.yourTextView);
  tv.setText(name);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer but I dont think it works, my app force closes. I think I might be doing it wrong, if you could tell me exactly what I need to put and how that would be great.

Comment: Check updated answer, in case of any error, post stack trace and relevant code!

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, for the aerobic_steps I get this error: The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (Aerobic_Steps)

Comment: Yeah I did that it works, the only problem I have now is when I view the training schedule class, it force closes again. I can view it when adding the text but I also want to be able to view it normally.

Comment: normally meaning without calling it from aerobics? In that case it force closes cuz it just can't find anything in bundle, so put a check for if bundle is null and handle it.

Comment: Yeah, without calling from the aerobics class, I have it linked to a different class which is the menu.

Comment: So just check : `if(bundle !=null) { retrieve required values}` else {remaining steps}. You may post a new question for this!

Comment: Sorry to ask but am not quite sure how to do that. Could you please put in the code.